# BeamerArticle: Box around text between frames with mdframed causes error

Tags: beamer, mdframed, beamerarticle

I am using `beamerarticle` and want to put a box around the content **between** frames and only when there is really content. Is that possible? I tried it with `mdframes` package quite symmetric to [Framing \frame using mdframed with beamerarticle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529690/framing-frame-using-mdframed-with-beamerarticle) but did not succeed as I got errors on compilation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\mode<article>{
\setbeamertemplate{frame begin}{\end{mdframed}}
\setbeamertemplate{frame end}{\begin{mdframed}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{testframe}
    content for testframe
\end{frame}

lalala interframetext

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{testframe}
    content for testframe
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

- the timing of your templates is wrong. The `frame begin` and `frame end` templates are executed when the frame environment has already began/is still going. This will create kind of a chain link between your mdframe and beamer's frame environments. You have to open and close your mdframe before or after the beamer frame.
- you also have to consider the edge cases, e.g. the first `\begin{frame}` which tries to close an environment which was never opened and the last `\end{frame}` which also creates an `mdframe` which is never closed.

---

```
%\documentclass{beamer}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\mode<article>{
\AfterEndEnvironment{frame}{\begin{mdframed}}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{\end{mdframed}}
}

\begin{document}

\mode<article>{\begin{mdframed}}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{testframe}
    content for testframe
\end{frame}

lalala interframetext

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{testframe}
    content for testframe
\end{frame}
\mode<article>{\end{mdframed}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, agreed, I did use the timing in a wrong way. Yet, I was wondering if you can in some way automatically detect, whether there is content in between? But probably it is the best way, as you suggested at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659402/beamerarticle-and-includeonlylecture?noredirect=1#comment1640716_659402, to use just explicit mdframed whenever I have text there...