# beamerarticle and includeonlylecture

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle, includeonlylecture

I am using for my lecture a one-content solution with two main files of documentclasses beamer/scrbook+beamerarticle. Now I want to make use of the command `\includeonlylecture` but it seems to not work. Here a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\includeonlylecture{v2}

\begin{document}

    \lecture{V1}{v1}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Heading V1}
    \end{frame}

    
    \lecture{V2}{v2}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Heading V2}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

The output still is

[image]

Comment: If you can save your lectures as separate files, you can use `\includeonly` in article mode.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but wasn't there an issue with `\include` and the`\mode`-commands? That is why I use `\input` instead...

Comment: Not a general issue, just  with certain modes which ignore non frame text. Personally, I would not use them, but warp these bits in `\mode<article>{...}`

Comment: .... as you also place your non frame contents in mdframes, you could create an environment which acts like a comment in beamer mode and like an mdframe in article mode. This would avoid all these problems with modes, chain linked environments, includeonlys etc.

Comment: The idea with a new environment that acts differently depending on the mode is really nice. Yet, this would not fix that `beamerarticle` is ignoring `includeonlylecture`, correct? Well I can then of course switch completely to `includeonly`on both levels...

Comment: You can use `\includeonly` in article mode and `\includeonlylecture` in beamer mode

Comment: But then I have to modify always two lines accordingly what I want to be included.

Comment: you can use a macro which will act like either of both depending on the mode

Comment: Which would also require renaming either the lectures or the files but yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\includeonly` if your are in article mode:

```
%\documentclass{beamer}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{v1.tex}
\lecture{V1}{v1}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Heading V1}
    \end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{v2.tex}
\lecture{V2}{v2}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Heading V2}
    \end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\mode<article>{\newcommand{\arnelikestoplaywithmodes}[1]{\includeonly{#1}}}
\mode<beamer>{\newcommand{\arnelikestoplaywithmodes}[1]{\includeonlylecture{#1}}}

\arnelikestoplaywithmodes{v2}

\begin{document}

\include{v1}
\include{v2}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice macro name ;)

Comment: @Arne I thought as you are using `scrbook`, you'd be used to such names: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418912/36296 :)

Comment: Was not aware of this. Hilarious. Thanks for mentioning :)